# Get new messages in messengers (Telegram, Whatsapp, Facebook-messenge, Snapchat, Viber)

Tags: telegram, whatsapp, facebook-messenger, snapchat

I want to write some script, I need to get new messages from chats (group, person) in `telegram, whatsapp, facebook-messenger, viber, snapchat`. The goal of script is to call some service if there are new messages in groups or person chats. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by integrating with each service's messaging API and establishing a webhook for each respective service.